# After programmatically segueing, The ViewController has not been dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, segue

When you press a button a custom segue is performed to start a game:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToGame", sender: nil)
```

I'm using sprite kit.  I have settings in the `GameViewController` and `GameScene` such that you play until you lose and when you do the gameScene sends a message to the view controller telling it to segue back to the initial view controller.  I do this as follows:

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   /*
 All code to set the scene is there
 */
    skView.presentScene(scene)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "segueToHomeScreen", name: "segueToHomeScreen", object: nil)}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    if self.isBeingDismissed() {
        println("Dismissed Vc")
    }else {
        println("still here")
    }
}

func segueToHomeScreen(){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToHomeScreen", sender: nil)
}
```

in my GameScene the code I used when you lose the game is:

```
func segueToHomeScreen() {
    notificationCenter.postNotificationName("segueToHomeScreen", object: nil)
}
```

The problem is the GameScene has not completely stopped when I segue back to the home screen.  I found this out by two things.  One, the `viewDidDisapper` function you see above, I get a log message of "still here".  Two, in gameScene I used this

```
 override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
     println("Scene On")
 }
```

When you lose the game and you are back at the home screen this function is still running.  **How can I stop the ViewController and GameScene from running after performing the segue to the home screen?**

Mot sure if this is related but I also get an error message:

> Warning: Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: See the answer I just posted in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794076/correct-way-of-removing-deleting-a-view-viewcontroller-from-the-stack-after-se/30794127#30794127. The details are slightly different but the answer is the same. Normal segues create a new view controller on top of the existing view controller and leave it in place. The only kind of segue that goes back is an unwind segue.

Comment: @Duncan I tried using the unwind segue and as you said it does dismiss the view controller completely , the problem is When I want to play again I'm not able to segue back a second time is there a way to fix that?